# sed substitute and show line number

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm working in bash trying to use `sed` substitution on a file and show both the line number where the substitution occurred and the final version of the line. For a file with lines that contain foo, trying with

```
sed -n 's/foo/bar/gp' filename
```

will show me the lines where substitution occurred, but I can't figure out how to include the line number. If I try to use `=` as a flag to print the current line number like

```
sed -n 's/foo/bar/gp=' filename
```

I get

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
```

I can accomplish the goal with `awk` like

```
 awk '{if (sub("foo","bar",$0)){print NR $0}}' filename
```

but I'm curious if there's a way to do this with one line of `sed`. If possible I'd love to use a single `sed` statement without a pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do it without listing the search pattern twice and using [command grouping](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Grouping-commands-101).

```
sed -n "/foo/{s/foo/bar/g;=;p;}" filename
```

**EDIT**: [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) helped me out there by mentioning that if the pattern space is empty, the *default* pattern space is the last one used, as mentioned [in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses). So you could get away with it like this:

```
sed -n "/foo/{s//bar/g;=;p;}" filename
```

Before that, I figured out a way not to repeat the pattern space, but it uses branches and labels. "In most cases," the docs specify, "use of these commands indicates that you are probably better off programming in something like awk or Perl. But occasionally one is committed to sticking with sed, and these commands can enable one to write quite convoluted scripts." [[source](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands)]

```
sed -n "s/foo/bar/g;tp;b;:p;=;p" filename
```

This does the following:

- `s/foo/bar/g` does your substitution.
- `tp` will jump to `:p` iff a substitution happened.
- `b` (branch with no label) will process the next line.
- `:p` defines label `p`, which is the target for the `tp` command above.
- `=` and `p` will print the line number and then the line.
- End of script, so go back and process the next line.

See? Much less readable...and maybe a distant cousin of [`:(){ :|:& };:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb#Defusing). :)

Comment: Interesting background info, but a simple tweak to your original command would have sufficed: `sed -n "/foo/{s//bar/g;=;p;}" filename`, taking advantage of `s//` defaulting to the most recently used context address (regex). However, the solution invariably outputs _2_ lines (line number first, then modified line) - unlike the OP's `awk` solution.

Comment: Yes, two lines. Join them with `sed ... filename | paste - -`

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks! Please feel free to promote to an answer, or edit mine. I can edit it in if you don't get to it in a little bit.

Comment: @JeffBowman: My pleasure; you did most of the work, so I'll let you edit the answer. One more observation: If you also want to make BSD/OSX `sed` happy, end the script with `p;}` rather than `p}`.

Comment: @glennjackman The `paste - -` trick is clever, but, unfortunately, the OP wants a single,`sed` command, without using a pipeline. Sounds like that can't be done, right?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done in any reasonable way with sed, here's how to really do it clearly and simply in awk:

```
awk 'sub(/foo/,"bar"){print NR, $0}' filename
```

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else use awk.